# Iteratively examine the values in a variable in a dataframe, and return the values of an adjacent variable in R

Tags: r, for-loop

I am trying to create a new variable (Nprice) in a dataframe in R. The values in Nprice depend on the values in a list of other vectors in the dataframe.

Here is my sample data

```
dataframe <- data.frame(
Comp = abs(rnorm(35)),
priceMar16 = rnorm(35),priceApr16 = rnorm(35), priceMay16 = rnorm
(35),priceJune16 = rnorm(35),priceJuly16 = rnorm(35),priceAug16 = rnorm(35),
cellchangeMar16 = rep(c("SP", "2xSP", "SP: SP", NA, NA), 7),
cellchangeApr16 = rep(c(NA, NA, "SP", "2xSP", "SP: SP"), 7),
cellchangeMay16 = rep(c("SP", NA, NA, "2xSP", "SP: SP"),7),
cellchangeJune16 = rep(c("SP: SP", NA, "SP", "2xSP", NA),7),
cellchangeJuly16 = rep(c(NA, "SP", "2xSP", "SP: SP", NA), 7),
cellchangeAug16 = rep(c("SP: SP", "SP", "2xSP", NA, NA), 7))
```

For each component ("Comp") I want to look up the value for cellchangeAug16, if it is NA, then I want to return the value of priceAug16 to the vector Nprice. If cellchangeAug16 is not NA, then I want to examine cellchangeJul16. If cellchangeJul16 is NA, then I want NPrice to be the value for priceJul16, if cellchangeJuly is not NA, then I want to go to cellchangeJun16; and iteratively down the list of columns for cellchange.

If there are no NA values for any of the cellchange variables for that component, then I want NPrice to be "No NP".

This is what I have tried

```
my_seq <- seq_along(dataframe)
my_seq <- my_seq[-1]

dataframe$Nprice <- for (i in my_seq) { test[i] <- ifelse 
((grepl("Cell",names(dataframe[i]),ignore.case=T))==F,next, 
ifelse(grepl("SP",dataframe[i]),dataframe[i-1],"")) }
dataframe$Nprice <- if (dataframe$Nprice == ""){"No SP"}
```

This returns the error message "13: In [<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, i, value = list(c(2016.03,  ... : replacement element 1 has 9238 rows to replace 9237 rows"

Can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [If the value in a variable is NA, return the value of the adjacent cell. If non-NA, examine the next cell, and so on; in R](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43057959/if-the-value-in-a-variable-is-na-return-the-value-of-the-adjacent-cell-if-non). You should edit that question, not post a new near-identical one.

Answer (score 0):

I figured this out. So if anyone is interested, here is how it can be done:

Create two subsets of the dataframe, which contain only the variables of interest

```
CellChange <- dataframe[,c(grep("Cell",colnames(dataframe),ignore.case = T))]
Prices <- dataframe[,c(grep("price",colnames(dataframe),ignore.case = T),
                               grep("Comp",colnames(dataframe),ignore.case = T))]
```

Find the location (new vector called 'Location') of the instances where the cell change value does not contain SP

```
Location <- vector()
for (i in 1:nrow(CellChange)) { temp <- CellChange[i,]
tempgrep <- min(grep("SP", temp, invert = T, ignore.case = T))
if (tempgrep == Inf) {Location[i] <- ""}
else Location[i] <- tempgrep }
```

For each of the locations in the Location vector, return the corresponding value in the Prices data

```
for (i in 1:length(Location)) {
if (Location[i] == "") {Prices$FinalValue[i] <- "No NP for last 12 months"} 
else { Prices$FinalValue[i] <- Prices[i, as.numeric(Location[i])] } 
}
```

Extract the information from the previous step into a dataframe

```
Finalvalue <- data.frame(Prices$FinalValue, Prices$Comp)
```

Merge this back into the original data

```
colnames(Finalvalue) <- c("FinalValue", "Comp")
dataframe <- merge(dataframe, Finalvalue, by.x = "Comp", all = T)
```